# Cópia de variável em angular 2(typescript)

Tags: angular

Preciso fazer uma cópia de um array sem usar referencia

**Exemplo**

```
var a = ["teste", "teste1"];
var b = a;

a[0] = "teste3";
b[0] = "teste4";
console.log(a) //mostrar teste3
console.log(b) //mostrar teste4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para arrays usando es6 vc pode Fazer assim:

```
var a = ["teste", "teste1"];
var b =[...a];

a[0] = "teste3";
b[0] = "teste4";

console.log(a) //mostrar teste3
console.log(b) //mostrar teste4
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso, obrigado ^^